# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Slim Framework

Tags: php, angularjs, slim

so this is it. I am running my API on a server, its running in localhost:8080 in the server.
I was told that in order to access the api from locally from my machinne (using vpn) the url is xxx.xxx.xxx:8080
So i tried that

```
$http({
  url:'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/login',
  method:"POST",
  data:{user:$scope.user, password:$scope.password}
})
```

and my api route is like this

```
$app->post('/login', function ($request, $response) {
  //Parametros que se pasan a la api
  $input  = $request->getParsedBody();
  $req = $input['usuario'];
  $md5pass = md5($input['password']);
  $sth = $this->db->prepare("query");
  //bindParam pasandole los parametros para evitar injecciones sql
  $sth->bindParam("password", md5($input['password']));
  $sth->bindParam("usuario", $input['usuario']);
  $sth->execute();
  $todos = $sth->fetchAll();
  $cliente_id = $todos->cliente_id;
   ....
```

but i get this error from chrome

```
OPTIONS http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

any idea what could it be? Do i need to change settings to my Slim configuration or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a so called: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) [Preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

You can try to add this small middleware to allow all preflight requests. Of course, you should add your own security logic.

```
// CORS preflight middleware
$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, $next) {
    if ($request->getMethod() !== 'OPTIONS' || php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
        return $next($request, $response);
    }

    $response = $next($request, $response);

    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', $request->getHeaderLine('Access-Control-Request-Method'));
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->getHeaderLine('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));

    return $response;
});
```

Comment: I just had to change it a bit, this is what it worked for me.
    $app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        return $response;
    });
    $app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
        $response = $next($req, $res);
        return $response
          ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
           ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-
           With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization, token')
           ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, 
        PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    });